# Can "shop" (related to selling or stores) be used as a transitive verb?

Tags: american-english, transitive-verbs

How is [shop](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/shop_2) used as a transitive verb? The only transitive meanings I can find are *reporting someone to police* or *Photoshopping an image*.

I found [one discussion about transitive 'shop'](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=539174), centered on what's being offered up for sale (a baseball player's contract), and related to American English sports writing:

> ...plans to shop Teixeira, who is eligible for free agency after 2008.

Most other instances I see are from retailers and seem to occur only in the form of a command/inducement:

> Shop Peapod today! [(mailer, online copy)](http://www.peapod.com/)
>   Shop our huge selection of products at great prices
>   [(online copy)](http://www.kmart.com/)
>   shop appliances [(section link)](http://www.sears.com/)

Do speakers actually say things like, "I shopped Store Foo" or "She shopped the selection at Store Bar" or "We shopped appliances"? Or is this peculiar to advertisements? I've had no luck figuring out how to search for usage examples so far.

Comment: By the way, other than the sports-star example, it is completely normaly with scripts or movie properties in Hollywood.  "Michael Bay is shopping around his new script."  And the "around" can be omitted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an idiom *to shop (something) around* which means, more or less, to present (something) to a variety of potential buyers to see who will make the best offer for purchase. The example given, “to shop Teixeira” is just a truncated version of this idiom, dropping the *around*.

Some examples of this idiom from COCA:

> - But how serious could he have been about leaving Sacramento if he didn't have a high-profile agent **to shop him around** the league, someone who might have bullied or bluff-ed the Kings into talling sign-and-trade with other teams?
> - For a fee, his company will build a prototype and **shop it around**. If a corporation bites, Davison shares royalties with inventors.
> - They get a good idea, **shop it around**, raise some capital, then sell it off to a bigger company
> - Insurers sometimes **shop patients around** to a series of IMEs, flying them out of state and putting them up at motels.
> - And how do you know if you're getting a fair shake? # " I always tell people to **shop it around**, " said Nedler. " Take it two or three places. You have to trust who you're dealing with.

The shortened version seems commonly used in a sports context:

> - In fact, with the trade deadline coming up Monday, the Bears ought to **shop him** now and try to retrieve something in return.
> - The idea, they said, was to be up front with free agent Monk during a time when he also could **shop himself** to the highest NFL bidder.

This truncated version possibly developed from cases like the first example above (*shop him around the league*), where the phrasal verb *to shop ___ around* was reanalyzed as a normal transitive verb *to shop ___* that takes an optional prepositional phrase with *around*—as in *around the league*. Notice that the example *shop patients around to a series of IMEs* uses “around **to**”, which is what you’d expect with a phrasal verb.

This idiom is not the same idiom as *to shop (a business)* or *to shop (a selection of products)*, which is what the other examples are. People definitely use *shop* in this way. Here are a few examples of this in COCA:

> - Draw up a grocery list for the " big " holiday meal before you go shopping. Divide the list by section and **shop the store** in that order.
> - Sam's Club stores are huge and carry not only electronics, but everything from auto accessories to food to pharmaceuticals... But: You may need **to shop the store** repeatedly to recoup the $35 annual membership fee.
> - " We **shop the farmers markets** for amazing things like raw dates on the stem, red burgundy okra, romanesco, and saturn peaches, " says Holly Vesecky of Holly Flora in Los Angeles.
> - I am a die hard fashionista and, you know, **I shop the sales**.
> - Before he could ink a deal, he was automatically switched to TXU Energy... His price jumped 71 percent overnight, to 18.8 cents a kilowatt hour from 11 cents. " No way was I going to pay that, " says Mr. Dreese. He was able **to shop the market** and switch to another retailer for 13.3 cents a kilowatt hour.

To me, this idiom *to shop ___* is different from *to shop **at** ___* because it implies a slightly more intense sense of intention to the shopping.

Comment: +1 This is what I had started writing. You did a much better job of it.

Comment: It may be just a personal thing, but my understanding of "to shop something/one around" implies "testing the market", so to speak. As in: maybe the thing or person potentially "up for sale" isn't normally "buyable" anyway, and that possibility is being investigated.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I think that’s about right. When I wrote “to present to a variety of potential buyers to see who will make the best offer for purchase”, I didn’t necessarily mean that a purchase would result.

Comment: @nohat @Fumble Fumble, I don't see that.  Simply, if you are "shopping a script around," it is for sale and that's that. You're trying to find a suitable/well-paying buyer.  If you are just testing the waters of having a lookee, you would use an expresion like testing the waters.  Once you're shopping a property around, it's for sale, your agent and legal are ready to wrap up a deal if you can find one!

Comment: The British National Corpus has two different hits for "shopped the": "shopped the markets" and "shopped the piece around". "Shopping the" gets 14 hits, but only one is relevant "shopping the thing around". I'm quite surprised as "shopping the markets", because I don't recognise the idiom.

Comment: @nohat, Thank you - this is exactly what I was wondering about! I also think you're right that "shop the market" is more intense than  "shop at" - it conveys that you're not just browsing, but going purposefully, to find specific items or the best bargain there. I guess that's why the advertisements want you to "Shop Store Foo today" rather than "Shop at Store Foo today".

Comment: @nohat -- Hi Nohat.  I'm not sure why you say it is "perhaps exclusively" used in a sports context.  **It is used very commonly in any business context.**  (Indeed - as all the examples you posted, show!!!)  It is particularly common in the entertainment business (sports, movies, video games, advertising, models, fashion etc).  But it's used normally in any business field.  I doubt I would have even thought of the sports-agency usage, unless the OP had mentioned that in particular.  Typical examples are shopping a startup, a new drug, a movie property, headhunting (any industry) etc etc.

Comment: @Joe I couldn’t find any examples of the truncated version (i.e. the version **without** *around*) in any contexts other than sports ones. Certainly the idiom *to shop* ____ *around* occurs in many contexts other than sports.

Comment: @nohat - I see what you mean nohat.  But wait, you can instantly find examples for, say, "shop a script" in the Hollywood context.

Comment: @Joe I couldn't find any examples of "shop a script" in COCA, COHA, or the Google Books corpora at http://corpus.byu.edu

Comment: @nohat, Hi Nohat, hmm, zillions of examples,  Google on exactly: ' "shop a script" hollywood ' for examples online.  Or just ask anyone in the film business!  Here's looking at you..

Answer (score 5):

It's certainly not standard English to **Shop Walmart**, for example. Any such usage is probably down to either ['marketese'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2853/what-does-the-word-marketese-mean) or the specialised vocabulary of the [baseball, etc.] sports transfer market and sports writers reporting thereof.

But you can certainly say **We shopped for ski accessories**, and countless people will have said **We shopped till we dropped**.

The usage OP is asking about seems to come down to whether **shop** can normally replace **buy [from]**, and the answer is it can't. Also it can't grammatically replace **sell**, or **offer for sale** except in the baseball player example - and I don't look to sports writers to tell me what's valid English for general use.

Comment: and also 'shop at...'

Comment: @rest_day: Surely. And of course you don't even need preposition + subject at all. **"What did you do yesterday?"  "We shopped"**.

Comment: @FumbleFingers both would be a tad different, no? "We shopped" and "We shopped at Walmart" or "We shopped at XYZ street"

Comment: It's not ignorance, it's baseball terminology.  I really recommend saving an "ignorance" analysis as a last resort.  There is almost always a much better explanation.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: Sigh. You're right again, thanks. I will rephrase.

Comment: @Fumble .. "to shop Walmart" is completely normal in the USA.  "Let's go shop the mall"  "I love to shop Macy's"  It's a little bit slang / Vally Girl / Sex in the City / sassy ... but completely normal.

Comment: @Joe Blow: Well you haven't put 'location' in your info page. But I suppose you're US, and I'm certainly not going to argue with you about what your fellow countrymen say. It sounds ignorant to me - but as @Kosmonaut flagged up, in the baseball terminology context it's just how they phrase things. We, of course, don't do baseball in the UK, and it would be ignorant of me to pronounce on their usage.

Comment: @Fumb --  hi Fumble! You suppose wrong, I am not US but lived there (and many other places) for many years (working with language).  Fumble, do you know the "Bill and Ted's excellent adventure" movies.  It's rather like that - deliberately "over the top" rather self-mocking "Valley-girl" type of language.  You know?  As others mentioned, I think the female character in Seinfeld uses it.  It's just a funny expression meaning **get out of here** or **you must be joking**.  I don't read it as *particularly* silly/ignorant...  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rF-SIQWLRsI

Comment: @Fumb but yes it's a very typical "US high school" "California" type of ditzy saying.  Hey - in the UK we have 17 year old female "ladettes" drunk senseless and peeing on bus stops they have set fire to before they smash each other's face with a bottle. There's no room for GB to be snobbish anymore sadly :-/

Comment: @Joe Blow: I hope I'm not snobbish about UK lexical prowess in general. I couldn't afford to be anyway, since my accent and idiomatic usages are decidedly 'left-field' to many RP speakers' ears. Anyway, once a particularly 'ungrammatical' form has gained at least *some* currency, many usages are somewhat tongue-in-cheek rather than 'ignorant', which is partly why I removed that word from my actual answer.

Comment: Online stores have tabs for shop kitchen supplies and the like but I haven't heard the format of *shop Walmart* spoken. However, it is highly similar to the format: *let's eat Subway (or insert other restaurant)*, which I hear often and at which I cringe.  Let's go shop Walmart (meaning let's go shop at Walmart) may be moving into common usage.  (I'm a Native American English speaker.)

Answer (score 0):

The use of "shop" as a transitive verb implies the preposition. "To shop Teixeira" is equivalent to "to shop out Teixeira", a slightly slang term for "to offer Teixeira's services" as in to sell his contract. "To shop Walmart" is understood as "to shop at Walmart", while "to shop shoes" is "to shop for shoes".

So grammatically, "shop" is not a transitive verb; it requires a preposition. However, colloquially it can be understood as such, and thus it may eventually become "official" over time as it passes into common usage. Such is the fluidity and organic quality of language.

Comment: "Shop out" and "shop around" (the term I normally hear used in baseball) are [phrasal verbs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrasal_verb) — the preposition is not an argument of the object.  This is why you can say "the Yankees shopped Texeira around" (with *around* coming at the end of the sentence) but you can't say "to shop shoes for".  In the latter case, *for* is an argument of the prepositional phrase "for shoes", rather than part of the verb.

Answer (score -1):

I've only heard it in the sense of sport star transfers.

But there is no reason why you can't use it. If there is a need for a transitive verb then go ahead - you have my official permission.